# Can't Enter newline in insert mode while using YouCompleteMe and Ultisnips

Tags: vim, youcompleteme, ultisnips

I can't press `Enter` in Insert Mode while using the above two plugins. Is there a way to fix this? Or reassign how YouCompleteMe handles `Enter`?

I'm using the default configuration for YouCompleteMe, and a simple config for Ultisnips as follows:

```
au FileType c :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes c
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-m>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir="~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/UltiSnips"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-k>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just run into the same issue and solved it. It does not have anything to do with YouCompleteMe though. To make a new line you first must end the completion pattern by, in your case, pressing Crtl + j then enter into a new line by pressing enter.